# Finding the limit points of $N_{\infty}$ if its a union of a set of natural numbers and $\infty$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

[image]

Kindly see what i did, and let me know if there is anything else I need to add or modify in my proof. I am hoping that I am good, but not sure.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question and solution don't match.

Comment: yeah, I am so sorry. I edited the question. Now, you all can see it.

Comment: You talk about $\Bbb R_\infty$ in the solution too. This is irrelevant.

Comment: I thought since the reals is a subset of naturals and vice versa, so maybe I can use that. Do you think its worthless using it? Then I will erase it.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right: all points of $\Bbb N$ are isolated as $\{0\} = \{x: x < 1\}=[0,1)$ and $\{n\}=(n-1,n+1)$ for $n \ge 1$. While $\infty$ has basic neighbourhoods of the form $(n,\infty]=\{x: x > n\}$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$. This is an infinite set (or just remark it contains $n+1 \neq \infty$ etc.) so $\infty$ is a limit point (the only one!) of $\Bbb N_\infty$.

So your solution is correct, but can be written more concisely. We don't need to consider subspaces (as you do), but only the order topology on $\Bbb N_\infty$ (in the order as described); we want to know *its* limit points, so its non-isolated points. Mentioning $\Bbb R$ is a red herring.

Comment: ok I won't mention about reals, will only deal with the naturals. But I have a question about singletons and doubleton's? Singletons are not going to be the limit points here, but why? Also, wat abt doubletons? Need a perfect explanation for this.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun doubleton? That is a two point set like $\{1,2\}$. They are not points, so not isolated points. I don't understand your question.

Comment: yeah, doubletons are the sets which contain 2 elements, i.e. {1,2}, {2,3} etc. Singletons are {1},{2},{3} etc.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun In a $T_1$ space (as all ordered spaces are) **no** finite set can have a limit point. This is trivial.